# sqlbulkcopy using sql CE

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, sqlbulkcopy

Is it possible to use SqlBulkcopy with Sql Compact Edition e.g. (*.sdf) files?

I know it works with SQL Server 200 Up, but wanted to check CE compatibility.

If it doesnt does anyone else know the fastest way of getting a CSV type file into SQL Server CE without using DataSets (puke here)?

Answer (score 24):

BULKCOPY is not supported in SQL CE. Here is the fastest way if you have a huge number of rows in your table; insert is too slow!

```
using (SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(yourConnectionString))
{
    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        cn.Open();

    using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.CommandText = "YourTableName";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;

        using (SqlCeResultSet rs = cmd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Updatable | ResultSetOptions.Scrollable))
        {
            SqlCeUpdatableRecord record = rs.CreateRecord();

            using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(yourTextFilePath))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    int index = 0;
                    string[] values = line.Split('\t');

                    //write these lines as many times as the number of columns in the table...
                    record.SetValue(index, values[index++] == "NULL" ? null : values[index - 1]);
                    record.SetValue(index, values[index++] == "NULL" ? null : values[index - 1]);
                    record.SetValue(index, values[index++] == "NULL" ? null : values[index - 1]);

                    rs.Insert(record);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Benchmark: table with 34370 rows

- with inserts: 38 rows written per second
- this way: 260 rows written per second

Comment: This method doesn't support Identity and rowversion columns types

Comment: Wow, was struggling with Insert and getting 20 - 30 rows a second, I'm sure this just did all 35,774 rows in less than 1 second (all my data was in an array in memory) so no bottle necks from the source.

Comment: I converted my code using SqlCeCommand and parameters to this and while not a 10x speed up it was twice as fast, thanks.

Comment: My previous code was trying to insert using entity framework 5 (turned off change tracking and validation, using just one savechanges call at the end) and sqlce, after leaving it to run for an hour and a half and coming back to find it still in progress, I killed the app!  Rewrote using the above for the insert portion and it now inserts the same 271,703 records in 27 seconds!

Comment: Unless I'm not grokking this (definitely possible), this seems to be getting the values from the database (StreamReader reading from "yourConnectionString"), and then inserting them back into the database...???

Comment: Thanks B. Clay Shannon, that was an error, i edited it and make it as a general txt source of data

Answer (score 9):

I have a SqlCeBulkCopy library here: http://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com - even support IEnumerable.

Comment: Does it support Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: Yes - it is a VS 2008 solution.

Comment: To use this, do I have to add all five of the .DLLs to my project? Or just some of them? Are they replacements for the "generic" SqlCe .DLLs, or are they additional to those?

Comment: They are additional, you do not need to copy the ddl files, they just need to be installed on the PC/Device.

Comment: Do you mean DLL files? So all five need to be on the path, or added as references to the project?

Comment: The only thing your TestSqlCeLib project references is ErikEJ.SqlCe.NetCF, so I'm assuming that's all I need.

Comment: Eriks Bulkcopy is much faster than the suggested way above. Just google it, the Link @ErikEJ posted is outdated

Answer (score 1):

Is possible to increase a lot this kind of operation. 
To turn this operation usefull (I mean fast and pretty safe), u can use CE DataAdapter.

By sample, no care about keys, the steps listed bellow can help u:

1. Make sure that sorce and target tables have same fields structure;
2. Clone a virtual datatable with a datatable from source database (your select);
3. Create a CE command with the table name as commandtext (TableDirect as commandtype);
4. Create a CE dataadapter from CE command;
5. Create a CE commandbuilder from CE dataatapter;
6. Pass the Insert command from CE commandbuilder to CE dataadapter;
7. Copy "n" batch rows from your source datatable to the target datatable (the clone), doing something like this:

   ```
   '... previous codes
   For Each currentRow In sourceTable.Rows
      'u can do RaiseEvent Processing(currentRow, totalRows) here with DoEvents
      If targetTable.Rows.Count < 100 Then
         targetTable.InportRow(currentRow)
         targetTable.Rows(targetTable.Rows.Count - 1).SetAdded
      Else
         '...Here you wll call the CE DataAdapter's Update method (da.Update(targetTable))
         '...and then be sure you clone the targetTable again, erasing all previous  rows.
         '...Do a clone again, don't do just a "clear" in the Rows collection.  
         '...If u have an Autoincrement it will break all Foreign Keys.
      End If
      Next
      '... next codes
   ```

With this way u can update several rows with no much time.

I've some applications using this method and the average rate is about 1500 rows per second in a table with 5 NTEXT fields (slow) and 800000 rows.

Of course, all depends of your table's structure. IMAGE and NTEXT are both slow datatypes.

P.S.: As I said, this method don't care so much about keys, so be carefull.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think that `SqlBulkCopy` is supported (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)). Perhaps throw the data in as xml and strip it apart at the server? SQL/XML is pretty good in 2005/2008.

You might also want to look at table-value-parameters, but I doubt that CE supports these.