# C# BulkCopy with SQL Server Compact Edition, is it possible?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, sqlbulkcopy

My intent is to copy excel data into SQL Server Compact Edition.

I have read the difference between SQL Server Compact and SQL Server from  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)  but couldn't find it out.

Also, know that constructor of SqlBulkCopy takes parameter of SqlConnection and not SqlCeConnection.

Here is my code:

```
public void importDataFromExcel(string excelFilePath)
{
        string sSQLTable = "Inflations";
        string myExcelDataQuery = "Select CUSIP,FM,TNT,CPI_INDEX from [Sheet1$]";
        string sExcelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + excelFilePath + ";Extended Properties=" + "\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\"";
        string sSqlConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\\Users\\abc\\Documents\\datafile.sdf;Password=12345;";

        OleDbConnection OleDbConn = new OleDbConnection(sExcelConnectionString);
        OleDbCommand OleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand(myExcelDataQuery, OleDbConn);
        OleDbConn.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dr = OleDbCmd.ExecuteReader();

        SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sSqlConnectionString);
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = sSQLTable;

        while (dr.Read())
       {
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
        }
        OleDbConn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606487/sqlbulkcopy-using-sql-ce) thread is related to your problem. You may also look at [library](http://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/), proposed for using also in that conversation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use my SqlCeBulkCopy library, available via NuGet for SQL CE 4.0, or otherwise available here: https://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/